# UML Class diagram: What is the meaning of attributes at lines?

Tags: uml, associations, class-diagram

Hello stackoverflow community:

I have never seen attributes at lines before. So could someone explain me where these have to be defined?

Usually we have attributes in the classes at the second row. So I am confuded about this notation.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

These are not "attributes", but these are association end names, which are also called "roles". It means the same as if the class `And` would have two properties `mlhs` and `mrhs` referring each to an `Expression` type.  It also means that class `Not` would have an `mexpr` property.

By the way:

- the [roles](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41184857/3723423) should be placed closer to the end of the association, at the side of interface. Otherwise they could be confused with the association name, which is yet something else.
- the aggregation diamond does not add any value in this model.
- lastly, you could replace the open arrow at the end of the association, which express navigability, with the dot notation which expresses ownership of the association-end and implies navigability.

Comment: Wait. I thought I got it right. The composition here (I forgot to color it black) is only to state that the parameter are of type interface or not? And the m should be the  ~ for packages.

Comment: @RackCloud no, the composition indicates if you delete a *Not* instance that also delete the associated *Expression* memorized through *expr*, and if you delete a *And* that also delete the associated *Expression* memorized through *lhs* and *rhs*. But here there is no composition, only aggregation

Comment: @RackCloud to use the visibility ~/package in this context is a non sense for me, are you sure they are not -/private ?

Comment: @RackCloud object composition does not require UML composition. Regarding UML composition, Bruno already answered. Sorry, I misread ~ for m (which is often used to name properties). Indeed, package visibility suggest that you carry-out outside the class a responsibility that belongs to the class. Sounds like a design smell if you don’t have a very strong justification. Also protected is not recommended since it causes nasty bugs (see discussions on LSP and the so called “history constraint”). Make it private. Offer read-only access via a getter if required ;-)